# Launch Cordova Windows app from push notification and navigate to specific page

Tags: cordova, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1, phonegap-pushplugin

I've written a Cordova app and am using PushPlugin for Push notifications. When a notification is tapped, I want to display a specific page in app. I've managed to do so for Android and iOS by sending the params as payload in notification and checking them in `$cordovaPush:notificationReceived` event.

For Windows, I'm sending these params as `Location`, but am neither able to trap the notification, nor check the params. I'm not sure whether the event `$cordovaPush:notificationReceived` is fired at all on Windows.

Did anyone have success with this?

Comment: I also have the same problem and searching on it for a long time. Hope somebody helps!